# How do i exit this while loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to get this loop down but I don't know how to break from it.

```
System.out.printf("Please enter your given name and surname (Enter 0 to return to main menu)%n");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        while (name.equals("0")) {
            System.out.printf(MENU_TEMPLATE);
            name = sc.nextLine();
```

if the user enters their name then the program will carry on as normal, but I'm having trouble doing this.

Comment: If you enter anything other than "0", that loop will exit.  If it's not, you have another loop you're not showing.

Comment: what is your whole scenario?

Comment: i'm creating a program where a student can see their marks on exams, but I want to make a student id method where each student gets a studentID, the code above is asking the user for their name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use a conditional, when you want to break the loop. Then you use the `break` command.

like

```
while (name != Integer.toString(0)) {
   if (name == "Salami") {
     break;
   }
}
```

another way to break the loop is to use a counter.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
//do some code here.
i++;
}
```

Comment: wouldn't there be an error as I declared the name as a string but in the loop, it's an integer?. I also should state many users will be using this program so wouldn't the if statement be useless?

Comment: oh right. fixed it. This would fix the loop, but honestly, it is conventional to break a loop with a condition if you know the condition will happen sooner or later. if you don't you use a counter. I added this to the example.